# ActiveMQ gives: "Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://localhost:61616" after around 10 000 messages

Tags: java, spring-boot, jms, activemq-classic, spring-jms

ActiveMQ gives: "javax.jms.JMSException: Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://localhost:61616. Reason: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: connect" after around 10 000 messages

Then after a some time (around 1-5 seconds) start to get messages with no issue.

I'm using Spring Boot 2.0.4 with very basic configuration:
`spring.activemq.broker-url=tcp://localhost:61616
spring.activemq.user=admin
spring.activemq.password=admin
spring.activemq.packages.trust-all=true`

I used JmsTemplate and now using spring integration, sadly the error is the same.

```
org.springframework.jms.UncategorizedJmsException: Uncategorized exception occurred during JMS processing; nested exception is javax.jms.JMSException: Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://localhost:61616. Reason: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: connect
at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsUtils.convertJmsAccessException(JmsUtils.java:311) ~[spring-jms-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsAccessor.convertJmsAccessException(JmsAccessor.java:185) ~[spring-jms-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:507) ~[spring-jms-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.send(JmsTemplate.java:584) ~[spring-jms-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.convertAndSend(JmsTemplate.java:661) ~[spring-jms-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.convertAndSend(JmsTemplate.java:650) ~[spring-jms-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.integration.jms.AbstractJmsChannel.doSend(AbstractJmsChannel.java:49) ~[spring-integration-jms-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:445) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:394) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:181) ~[spring-messaging-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:160) ~[spring-messaging-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47) ~[spring-messaging-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:108) ~[spring-messaging-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:426) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:336) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:227) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:115) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:158) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:132) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:105) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:73) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:445) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:394) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:181) ~[spring-messaging-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:160) ~[spring-messaging-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47) ~[spring-messaging-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:108) ~[spring-messaging-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.convertAndSend(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:150) ~[spring-messaging-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.convertAndSend(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:142) ~[spring-messaging-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.send(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:415) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.invokeGatewayMethod(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:528) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.doInvoke(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:469) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.invoke(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:460) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
```

What can cause this type of error, i dont see anything in activemq logs, but error is persistent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The resolution was adding org.apache.activemq:activemq-pool and configuring the PooledConnectionFactory:

`spring.activemq.pool.enabled=true
 spring.activemq.pool.max-connections=50`

Enabling pool is not enough in Spring Boot as autoconfiguration checks for dependency.

Comment: We have tried by setting above properties and dependencies and also used PooledConnectionFactory instead of ActiveMQConnectionFactory, but still it is not working. If possible can you please give detailed answer ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Below is a solution with bean creation:

```
@Bean(name = "activemqConnectionFactory")
public PooledConnectionFactory connectionFactory(@Qualifier("activemqRedeliveryPolicy") RedeliveryPolicy redeliveryPolicy) {
    ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
    connectionFactory.setBrokerURL("tcp://" + env.getProperty("queue.url"));
    connectionFactory.setTrustAllPackages(true);

    PooledConnectionFactory pooledConnectionFactory = new PooledConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    pooledConnectionFactory.setMaxConnections(8);
    return pooledConnectionFactory;
}
```